# Rest Template Retrieve Status Code from Image URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to know the return status code from an image URL, for example:

```
http://img.test.com/news/1439911080563855663.jpg
```

This URL might return `404 (NOT_FOUND)` or an actual image in `JPG`, in this case `200 (OK)`, how can i check the status return by image url?

Normally we can use `restTemplate` to check for status in rest endpoint:

```
ResponseEntity<YourResponse> responseEntity =
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://your.url.here", YourResponse.class);

System.out.println(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
```

How can we do it with `restTemplate` for image url?

Answer (score 0):

Establish a connection and get the result code!

```java
URL url = null;
int code = 0 ;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            code = connection.getResponseCode();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(String.valueOf(code));
```